# como hacer un return a una función de JavaScript con nodejs

Tags: javascript, nodejs, json, express, csv

hoy estaba haciendo unas pruebas con un formateador de csv en nodejs, pero el formateador me devuelve un objeto cuando le hago `console.log`, pero cuando quiero hacer un returnt a la función no me devuelve nada la función, ya que la quiero usar en un proyecto con Node.js y una ruta

codigo que se utilizo

```
controller.csvConverJson = (req, res) => {
    data = [];
    csvArchivo = "test.csv";
    result = csvConverJson(data, csvArchivo)
    console.log(result);
} 

function csvConverJson(data, name)  {
    var data = [];
    fs.createReadStream('src/csv/'+ name)
    .pipe(csv())
    .on('data', (rows)=> {
        data.push(rows)
    })
    .on('end',()=>{
        return data ;
    })
    
}
```

ahora una imagen con toda la información del código

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

alguien me puede ayudar a saber que es lo que esta fallando

Comment: createReadStream es una operación asíncrona, así que vas a tener que encontrar una forma de manejar tu función de manera asíncrona para poder retornar el valor, trata de utilizar promesas

Comment: Tal como te comentan, todo lo que necesites hacer con la variable `data` debes hacerlo dentro del método que maneja el evento `end`. En vez de hacer `return data;` allí vas a trabajar con esa variable, sea para mostrarla por consola o devolverla al cliente. De todas formas, es necesario que te documentes sobre procesos asíncronos en Javascript. Saludos